# "The connection was closed unexpectedly" sending to an HTTP 0.9 IP Phone

Tags: c#, .net, http, dotnet-httpclient, http-0.9

I am new to C# and I am trying to perform a GET request to an IP phone on my network to remotely dial a number. I am receiving an exception and I am unsure how I can establish why, as I cannot retrieve any error code. This is the code I am using:-

```
// Create a new HttpClient instance
var client = new HttpClient();

// Command to dial number
string dial = "http://xxx.xxx.x.x/command.htm?number=4553535345354";

try
{
    // Response
    HttpResponseMessage response = new HttpResponseMessage();
    response = await client.GetAsync(dial);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        // Do other things
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show(response.StatusCode.ToString());
    }
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Could not call: " + err.Message);
}
```

When I run this code I receive the caught exception with message "An error occurred while sending this request". The only other additional information I can see regarding the exception is "A first chance exception of type 'System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException' occurred in mscorlib.dll"

*** Updated ***

---

---

> Could not call: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: An error
>   occurred while sending the request. ---> System.Net.WebException: The
>   underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.
>
> at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)
>
> at
>   System.Net.Http.HttpClientHandler.GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
>
> --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task
>   task)
>
> at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)
>
> at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
>
> at AutoDialer.Form2.d__0.MoveNext() in
>   c:\Form2.cs:line 175

** Updated 26/14 Fiddler Results **

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Moved Temporarily Location
```

Protocol Violation Report:-

```
79  The Server did not return properly-formatted HTTP Headers. Maybe missing altogether (e.g. HTTP/0.9), maybe only \r\r instead of \r\n\r\n?
```

Extended Checks:-

```
182 [HTTPLint] With rare exceptions, servers MUST include a DATE response header. RFC2616 Section 14.18
```

Comment: Don't just use `err.Message`. Show `err.ToString()` in case there's more to it than that.

Comment: Thanks I have updated with full response

Comment: So, your task is now simpler: determine why "The connection was closed unexpectedly"

Comment: I think the problem might be because there are no headers been returned. 15 The Server did not return properly-formatted HTTP Headers. Maybe missing altogether (e.g. HTTP/0.9), maybe only \r\r instead of \r\n\r\n? -- How can I overcome this? The desired action works fine, but it throws an exception.

Comment: How did you determine that no headers are returned?

Comment: I made the request and then monitored using Fiddler

Comment: Ok, and I now presume that when you say "the desired action works fine", you mean that the IP phone dialed the number correctly, and I presume that you confirmed that it was the correct phone number? In that case, please post for us (in your question), the results from Fiddler. If that `HTTP/0.9` is accurate, then it may just be that `HttpClient` has no support for HTTP 0.9.

Comment: Yeah the IP phone successfully dials the number and the number is correct, although this error still happens regardless of whether the number is correct or not.

Comment: Check the phone's documentation. If all it requires is [`GET http://xxx.xxx.x.x/command.htm?number=foo\r\n`](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/AsImplemented.html) and the response is something like `OK`, you might be better off using a plain socket, or the somewhat more user-friendly [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient(v=vs.110).aspx). And perhaps there already exist some (un)managed libraries for the brand.